# UILocalNotification firedate from picker

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to implement an alarm type app that sets a UILocalNotification from a UIDatePicker (only time, no date). I kind of have it working except for the fact that lets assume it is **5:00 PM** when the user tries to set the alarm. If they try to set the alarm for **4:45 PM**
(let us assume they are doing this for the following day) it wont set the UILocalNotification. I am sure that it is because of my code and specifically the "setHour" or "setMinute" or the way I have the my nsdates with the calendar. If anyone can tell me what I need to do to get it work, it would be appreciated.

the name of the UIDatePicker is

```
   datePick
```

Thanks!

```
UILocalNotification *futureAlert;
futureAlert = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
//[dateComps setDay:item.day];
//[dateComps setMonth:item.month];
//[dateComps setYear:item.year];
[dateComps setHour:11];
[dateComps setMinute:46];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
futureAlert.fireDate = [datePick date];    
futureAlert.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
futureAlert.alertBody= @"time to wake up";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:futureAlert];
[futureAlert release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this code lines:

```
double interval = [datePick.date timeIntervalSinceNow]; // time interval
if (interval < 0) // if time is earling at this time
  interval += 86400; // for set this time at next day
futureAlert.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: interval];
futureAlert.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```

where **interval** in your case will equal to 85500 secs. In 24 hours a 86400 secs, 15 min - 900 secs, then a 23 hours 45 min - 85500 secs (86400 - 900).

So, you can calc a interval seconds and use it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry you kind of lost me with "interval". What do you suggest I declare that as/ do with it again? Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Just to verify you set this up because in my example I said 4:45 pm which is a difference of 23 hours and 45 minutes. But remember it is an alarm clock app. I do not control what time the user chooses to set an alarm. The difference will not always be 23 hours 45 minutes. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: And based on your code the datepicker is not being used anymore correct? is this not the time that will be read into the local notification?

Comment: Thanks again but its still not working. I think it may have to do something with UILocalNotification thinking its in the past so its not registering. Again the issue is if I try to pick a time earlier than what the current time is. So if its 8 pm now, and I try to set the alarm to 7 pm it will not register. Any other ideas? Will accept if we can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much! Will accept. Can I ask one last favour from you since you seem to have a very good understanding of this? For example If I set the alarm for 5 minutes from now it gives me the wrong date for when the notification will be fired. It is one day ahead for some reason? Any idea? Sorry for the hassle and thank you:)

Comment: wrong date? **interval** what value have? not a 300 ? I don't understand a situation and problem

Comment: I need to display to the user on what date there alarm will go off. I retrieve this date from the notification when it is set. The date it is giving me is always one day ahead of the actually day it is today. So if today is August 15 and I set the alarm to fire 5 minutes from now, it will ring in 5 minutes but the date on the notification is august 16. Thanks

Comment: PLease create a new question with your code and put here. I will answer.